# Javascript - Increment Number in Form

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I am just trying to increment a number in a form. This works but the input is big, tried to size with no luck.  And I don't want the increment up/down inside the input box.  Changing the box to text, gets me the right sizing and no up/down. But the increment doesn't work.

Is there an easier way.  Also when I put inside a `<form>` tag, the plus minus button don't work.

```js
function HaFunction() {
  document.getElementById("HNumber").stepUp();
}

function HmFunction() {
  document.getElementById("HNumber").stepDown();
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="number" id="HNumber" class=verd15 value="0">
<span class=verd13>
  <button onclick="HaFunction()"><b>+</b></button>
  <button onclick="HmFunction()"><b>-</b></button>
</span>
```

Comment: If you put it into a `<form>`, the buttons default to `type="submit"`. Use `type="button"` to override this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the input smaller with CSS:

```
<input style="width:40px" type="number" id="HNumber" class=verd15 value="0">
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Ya I get the width, but it still leaves the up/don increment arrows.

Comment: As @Barmar wrote above - you can increment it in javascript and then fill the new value back to the input

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function that increments the number in a text input.

If you have a form, make sure your buttons use `type="button"`. By default it's `type="submit"`, so clicking on the button will submit the form and you'll reload the page.

```js
function addToInput(element, amount) {
  var val = parseInt(element.value, 10) || 0;
  val += amount;
  element.value = val;
}

function HaFunction() {
  addToInput(document.getElementById("HNumber"), 1);
}

function HmFunction() {
  addToInput(document.getElementById("HNumber"), -1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Number: <input type="text" id="HNumber" class=verd15 value="0">
  <span class=verd13>
    <button type="button" onclick="HaFunction()"><b>+</b></button>
    <button type="button" onclick="HmFunction()"><b>-</b></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes works until I put the input code inside <form> tag then everything craps out.  Like previous examples I'm using.  Also, weirdly, formatting wise puts the Input infront of text instead of after.

Comment: Did you change to `type="button"` like I suggested above?

Comment: Can't reproduce the formatting problem, it's probably related to your CSS.